# Image could not be loaded from PHP script on same webserver as website

Tags: php, html

I've implemented a contact form with a captcha that should be loaded from "/contact/show-captcha.php?rand=1". The captcha displays correctly on the local development server but fails to load, when the site is moved to the actual webhosting server online (both run on PHP 8.1).

This is the HTML where the image should be loaded to

```
 <div class='container' id="captcha-element">
                      <div>
                          <img src="/contact/show-captcha.php?rand=1" id="scaptcha_img" alt="Captcha-Bild" />
                      </div>
                      <input type='text' placeholder="Captcha" name='scaptcha' id='scaptcha' maxlength="10" />
                      <br />
                      <span id='contactus_scaptcha_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                      <div class='short_explanation'>
                          <a href='javascript: refresh_captcha_img();'>Captcha erneut laden</a>.
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

It calls show-captcha.php

```
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
require_once("./include/captcha-creator.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['fg_validate_captcha']))
{
    $captchaobj = new FGCaptchaCreator('scaptcha');
    header("pragma: no-cache");
    header("cache-control: no-cache");

    if(!$captchaobj->ValidateCaptcha($_POST['scaptcha']))
    {
        echo "Captcha ist falsch. Bitte erneut versuchen!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success";
    }
}
else
{
    $captcha = new FGCaptchaCreator('scaptcha');
    header("pragma: no-cache");
    header("cache-control: no-cache");
    $captcha->DisplayCaptcha();
}
?>
```

which calls

```
function DisplayCaptcha()
    {
        $this->Create();
        $session_var = $this->getSessionVarName();
        $_SESSION[$session_var] = $this->getCaptchaPwd($this->code);

        $this->ShowCaptcha();
    }
```

and then

```
 function ShowCaptcha()
    {
        $this->DrawChars($this->code);
        $this->DrawLines();
        $this->image = $this->Blur($this->image);
        $this->image = $this->Distort($this->image);
        $this->SendImage();
    }
```

```
function SendImage()
   {
      header('Content-type: image/png');

      imagepng($this->image);
   }
```

Firefox DevTools says "Image could not be loaded" (not the exact translation since I'm running the browser in German. Could it be caused by missing libraries on the online webserver or errors in a .htaccess file? I haven't tried anything yet for fear of destroying more than I could fix and because it works on the local PHP server.

This is the error on the online server:

[image: error on the online server]

How it should look (screen taken while running the site on the local server):

[image: how it should look]

Comment: Are you sure, that your image is really located at the webroot of your server at the remote site? Maybe it has problems, because you are operating under a virtual root? Can you put a plain picture with a similar path and check if that gets displayed?

Comment: I've just uploaded a picture cards.png to /contact and it displays correctly. The captcha is being created by a PHP script

Comment: Do you have access to the error log of your webserver? If so, does it display anything when you display the page? Does the image display correctly if you call the image page directly?

Comment: Thank you for this tip! That brings me closer to the actual problem Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 0.2666350628521072 to int loses precision in /home/.sites/923/site1478415/web/mitech/contact/include/captcha-creator.php on line 257          ```imagecopyresampled($image_out, $im, $x, $d, $x, 0, 1, $height-$d, 1, $height);```

Comment: Thanks again, it works now, I had to round the float and cast it to an int

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Chris Glad I was able to help. Happy coding. :)